# using googlemaps api to geocode addresses using php and mysqli

Tags: php, google-maps-api-3, mysqli

I'm trying to update a field in a mysqli database. I am trying to use the googlemaps api to fill in the lat/lng geocode into the database. I know googlemaps has a usage limit, but I made a project in the Google developers console and made an API key. But nothing I do is working -- I still get the OVER_QUERY_LIMIT error. (I went over the limit, I guess, in trying to troubleshoot my code.)

Is this a lost cause? Do I have to look up the lat/lng of each address *by hand*? How can I get the googlemap lat/lngs for each of my (400-odd) addresses?

Here is my php code:

```
include_once ('constants_test.php'); 
   // connect to database
    $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME); 
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            printf("Connect failed: %s", mysqli_connect_error());
            exit();
    }

    date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
    $q = "SELECT provider_ID, location FROM `data` where point = ''";
    $result = $mysqli->query($q);

    while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
         $location = $row['location'];
         $provider = $row['provider_ID'];
         set_time_limit ( 120 );
         geocode($location, $provider);
    }

    function geocode($address, $provider){

    // url encode the address
    $address = urlencode($address);

    // google map geocode api url
    $url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address={$address}&sensor=false";

    // get the json response
    $resp_json = file_get_contents($url);

    // decode the json
    $resp = json_decode($resp_json, true);
    echo $resp['status'];
    // response status will be 'OK', if able to geocode given address 
    if($resp['status']=='OK'){

        // get the important data
        $lati = $resp['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'];
        $longi = $resp['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'];
        $formatted_address = $resp['results'][0]['formatted_address'];

        // verify if data is complete
        if($lati && $longi && $formatted_address){
            $new_location = "(" . $lati . "," . $longi . ")";
            $mysqli2 = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME); //open db conn
            $new_q = "Update `data` set point = '" . $new_location . "' where provider_ID = '" . $provider . "'";
            echo $new_q;    

            $result2 = $mysqli2->query($new_q);

        }else{
            return false;
        }

    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding a key does not remove the rate limit or the quota, it might increase the available quota; but you still need to deal with those.

Comment: do the api searches in batches of say 200 per day, or remove the api key and connect via a vpn / tor proxy

Comment: Even when I limit the query to one record and put it on my production server (which I haven't been using today), I get the OVER_QUERY_LIMIT response.